# unhandled error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, bots

```js
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

const path = require('path');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
// Import required bot configuration.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
dotenv.config({ path: ENV_FILE });

const restify = require('restify');
const { QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');
// Import required bot services.
// See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');

// This bot's main dialog.
const { MyBot } = require('./bot');

// Create HTTP server
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log('\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator');
    console.log('\nTo talk to your bot, open the emulator select "Open Bot"');
});
 
// Create adapter.
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about how bots work.
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
 });

// Map knowledge base endpoint values from .env file into the required format for `QnAMaker`.
const configuration = {
    knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
    endpointKey: process.env.QnAAuthKey,
    host: process.env.QnAEndpointHostName
 };

// Catch-all for errors.
const onTurnErrorHandler = async (context, error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    // NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    //       application insights.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError] unhandled error: ${ error }`);
  

    // Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in Bot Framework Emulator
    await context.sendTraceActivity(
        'OnTurnError Trace',
        `${ error }`,
        'https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error',
        'TurnError'
    );

    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity('The bot encountered an error or bug.');
    await context.sendActivity('To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.');
};

// Set the onTurnError for the singleton BotFrameworkAdapter.
adapter.onTurnError = onTurnErrorHandler;

// Create the main dialog.
const myBot = new MyBot(configuration, {});

// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        // Route to main dialog.
        await myBot.run(context);
    });
});

// Listen for Upgrade requests for Streaming.
server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
    // Create an adapter scoped to this WebSocket connection to allow storing session data.
    const streamingAdapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
        appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
        appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
    });
    // Set onTurnError for the BotFrameworkAdapter created for each connection.
    streamingAdapter.onTurnError = onTurnErrorHandler;

    streamingAdapter.useWebSocket(req, socket, head, async (context) => {
        // After connecting via WebSocket, run this logic for every request sent over
        // the WebSocket connection.
        await myBot.run(context);
    });
});
```

After creating the QnA bot using Microsoft azure using the editor VS code, I tried to test it in the emulator I get the following error " [onTurnError] unhandled error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". Can someone help me with this?
I followed the SDK4 tutorial-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-add-qna?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript

Thanks,
Rujuta

Comment: Could you please provide the code as you've written it so far? For all we know you could have simply made a mistake in a single line.

Comment: Sharing the index.js file

Comment: Already i think i see the issue. Your first console log uses the wrong inverted comma and hence is not seen as a string. in fact you have a few console interactions with the incorrect string marking symbol. Try fixing those first (please note I have no experience with this language. and it might actually be correct)

Comment: thanks for trying to help Grand J but that didnt make any difference :)

Comment: Is this error produced from the error handler output or the editor? The difference being if we see the editor said the error then your code is wrong. But if the handler said the error then the issue may lay outside of this code segment entirely. It could also be an issue with the connection

Comment: i think you are right... th editor runs the code but when i test it on the emulator and type a message to the bot this is when i get the error